# OpenCV on_low_height_thresh_trackbar() parameter clarification

Tags: c++, opencv

Given the following program code:

```
void on_low_height_thresh_trackbar(int, void*);
void on_high_height_thresh_trackbar(int, void*);
int low_height = 50, high_height = 85;

int main()
{
    img_Original = cv::imread("ROI1.jpg", 0);
    cv::medianBlur(img_Original, img_Median, 5);

    cv::namedWindow("original image");
    cv::namedWindow("selected image");

    cv::createTrackbar("Low height", "selected image", &low_height, 255, on_low_height_thresh_trackbar);
    cv::createTrackbar("High height", "selected image", &high_height, 255, on_high_height_thresh_trackbar);

    cv::imshow("original image", img_Original);
    on_low_height_thresh_trackbar(low_height, 0);
    on_high_height_thresh_trackbar(high_height, 0);

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}

void on_low_height_thresh_trackbar(int, void*)
{
    low_height = cv::min(high_height - 1, low_height);
    cv::setTrackbarPos("Low height", "selected image", low_height);
    cv::inRange(img_Median, low_height, high_height, img_Ranged);
    cv::imshow("selected image", img_Ranged);
}
void on_high_height_thresh_trackbar(int, void*)
{
    high_height = cv::max(high_height, low_height + 1);
    cv::setTrackbarPos("High height", "selected image", high_height);
    cv::inRange(img_Median, low_height, high_height, img_Ranged);
    cv::imshow("selected image", img_Ranged);
}
```

why should we need this two formal parameters `int` and `void*` in this callback function:

```
void on_low_height_thresh_trackbar(int, void*)
```

I think they are of no use.

Comment: Because when OpenCV calls it, it passes two parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since those are callbacks, they are called by OpenCV when the trackbar position changes and you're not supposed to call them yourself.

The `int` parameter is the new trackbar position, the `void*` is a pointer to arbitrary "user data".

If you pass a pointer as the `userdata` argument to `createTrackbar`, that pointer will be passed back to the callback when it is called.
In C++, it's very common to pass a pointer to an object as the "user data".
You could, for instance, write a `TrackBar` class that encapsulates a trackbar and passes `this` as the "user data".

Most callback interfaces provide a way to let your own data make a "round trip" through it in this way.